# Try - Catch y Variable no inicializada

Tags: java, try-catch

acabo de aprender la estructura básica del Try-Catch e hice un pequeño código para probarlo, pero me da un error de variable no inicializada. Alguien me puede instruir un poco sobre esto? Dejo el código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Variables
    String nomApel1, nomApel2;
    int edad1, edad2;
    boolean repeat = true;

    while (repeat) {
        //Pidiendo valores de variables al usuario.
        try {
            nomApel1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre y apellido de persona 1: ");
            edad1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Edad de la persona 1: "));
            nomApel2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre y apellido de persona 2: ");
            edad2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Edad de la persona 2: "));
            repeat = false;
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            System.out.println("Dato inválido, intentalo de nuevo.\n");
        } finally {
            //En todas las variables aquí me dice error de inicialización.
            if (edad1 > edad2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos de la persona mayor: \nNombre completo: " + nomApel1 + ".\nEdad: " + edad1 + ".");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos de la persona mayor: \nNombre completo: " + nomApel2 + ".\nEdad: " + edad2 + ".");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El error que te da es porque tienes que dar un valor a las variables nomApel1, nomApel2, edad1 y edad 2.

La explicación es muy simple, try catch finally es una estructura que sirve para controlar las excepciones que te puedan "saltar".

En tu código, imagina que da una excepción a la hora de recoger el valor de nomApel1 en esta instrucción:

```
nomApel1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre y apellido de persona 1: ");
```

Al dar una excepción, va a ir a la zona del catch (Ahí tienes todo bien), pero luego va a ejecutar la zona del finally y es ahí donde te va a dar problemas ya que, al no poder haber recogido los datos de edad1, edad2... no vas a poder ni compararlas ni mostrar su valor.

Para evitar esto, como te ha dicho el compañero @Dev.Joel en su respuesta, deberías dar algún valor inicial tanto a edad1 y edad2 como a nomApel1 y nomApel2 que puede ser así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
//Variables
String nomApel1 = "";
String nomApel2 = "";
int edad1 = 0;
int edad2 = 0;
boolean repeat = true;

while (repeat) {
    //Pidiendo valores de variables al usuario.
    try {
        nomApel1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre y apellido de persona 1: ");
        edad1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Edad de la persona 1: "));
        nomApel2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nombre y apellido de persona 2: ");
        edad2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Edad de la persona 2: "));
        repeat = false;
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        System.out.println("Dato inválido, intentalo de nuevo.\n");
    } finally {
        //En todas las variables aquí me dice error de inicialización.
        if (edad1 > edad2) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos de la persona mayor: \nNombre completo: " + nomApel1 + ".\nEdad: " + edad1 + ".");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Datos de la persona mayor: \nNombre completo: " + nomApel2 + ".\nEdad: " + edad2 + ".");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Ahora el problema es que si tienes una excepción te dara los valores 0 para los int y "" para los String pero ya podrás ejecutar el programa sin problemas

Answer (score 7):

Es muy común este error, En Java al declarar variables locales es decir dentro de un método por ejemplo *(para su caso el main)* no se añade valores por defecto en su inicialización como sucede cuando lo declara una variable a nivel de clase ,  por tal motivo deberá inicializar con algún valor dichas variables, debe tener claro tres puntos.

```
int a;  //declaración
a = 2 ;// inicialización
int a = 2; // declaración e inicialización
```

Entonces en su ejemplo podría inicializar a `0`, los `int` y a null los `String` por ejemplo como lo hace con su variable booleana y problema solucionado.

```
String nomApel1=null; nomApel2 = null;
int edad1=0; edad2 = 0;
```